# При добавление в базу пишет "undefined", в чем ошибка?

Tags: jquery, ajax, база-данных, mysql

Помогите новичку!

есть форма

```
<form id="feedb" name="feedb"  method="POST" action="action.php">
   <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="inp" placeholder="Ваше имя"  required="Введите имя"  />
  <input type="text" name="mail" id="mail" class="inp" placeholder="Ваш e-mail" required="Введите e-mail" />
  <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit"  class="button" value="Отправить" />
</form>
```

скрипт

```
<script>
    var name = $('#feedb p:nth-of-type(1) input').val();
    var mail = $('#feedb p:nth-of-type(2) input').val();

    $('#feedb').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            data: "name="+name+"&mail="+mail+"&action=add",
            url: 'action.php',
            success: function(data) {
                alert('Данные успешно сохранены')
            }

        });

    });
</script>
```

и файл пхп:

```
<?php

$name=$_POST["name"];
$mail=$_POST["mail"];

$dblink = mysql_connect($server, $user, $password);

if($dblink)
echo 'Соединение установлено.';
else
die('Ошибка подключения к серверу баз данных.');

$database = 'fleurdl_123';
$selected = mysql_select_db($database, $dblink);
if($selected)
echo ' Подключение к базе данных прошло успешно.';
else
die(' База данных не найдена или отсутствует доступ.');

$query = "INSERT INTO `users`(`name`, `mail`) VALUES ('".$name."','".$mail."')";

mysql_query($query);
mysql_close($dblink);
```

?>

Comment: В функции ajax у вас переменные mail и name не определены. Должно быть name = $('#name').val() и mail соотвественно.

Comment: поменял на var name = $('#name').val();
        var mail = $('#mail').val();

Comment: пустую строку добавляет

Comment: Присваивание `name` и `mail` необходимо поместить внутрь функции `$.ajax`

Comment: спасибо, разобрался.

Answer (score 1):

У вас в js селекторы неверные для name и mail. Тег абзаца 'p' там явно лишний.